# Is JW flash Player able to perform live streaming?

Tags: flash, streaming, jwplayer, live-streaming

I need a flash video component which I can control via javascript and can do both:

A. capture the stream from web camera and audio and publish it to server via RTMP

B. play the published stream

I have found the JW Player to be able to do B, but after reading everything I could find about it, I am still not sure whether it is possible to do A (doesn't matter if it is only in the paid version). Every time I am almost sure that it is only a player and cannot do A, I read something that confuses me.

Can somebody who is using it regularly clarify this issue for me?

Comment: The JW Player just plays the streams, it can't capture them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Additionaly I would like to ask you whether you know or have heard/read about any such component which could do what I am looking for?

Comment: I don't know of one, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do your requirement with only JW player.

For this, the better solution is going forward with Kaltura. [Look this article](http://www.wowza.com/news/kaltura-teams-with-wowza-to-launch-new-live-video-streaming-capability)

You can do RTMP integration like Wowza/Red5 servers.[Guide here](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Wowza-Media-Server-Integration-With-Kaltura-CE5)

Also You have to enable the HLS to do the live streaming. All of them were open source. [Guide to HLS](https://github.com/arrivu/beacon/wiki/Installing-Wowza-and-Integration-with-Kaltura-for-Live-Streaming)

It will be easier to do the streaming using the same Kaltura player.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read the articles you provided and some additional information about the kaltura player and platform but I am unsure about one thing: is it possible to build a website (with kaltura and wowza/red5 in the middle) where 2 people with only browser and flash installed would be able to make a video call (in other words - they would publish their immediate webcam stream to the server from where the other party could watch it live)? I understood that you have to have some additional SW installed if you want to publish live streams with Kaltura